# Folding versus taglist

Tags: vim, ctags, folding, taglist

When I started to use `taglist` and `ctags` I stopped using `folding`.

Are there some reasons to still use `folding` of code when you use
`ctags` and `taglist`?

I can imagine only two examples. When I have large pieces of code or functions
that are over the whole screen. Or when I want to hide comments.

Is there some main trick of `folding` I don't know about?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much it.

Folding is about hiding sections of code.
Tags are about jumping to pieces of code.

Whatever you want to do with either of those purposes is valid.  Example, I've used folding on big chunks of code to verify that indenting custom text lined up correctly.

The only other "trick" of folding is that it makes you win the lottery if you use it right.  But those of us that know the trick aren't going to tell.